# Unable to move character to right position using SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am currently having problem moving a character right and showing him like he's running but after i press right key it moves right for one time and then when i enter left it goes left again but pressing right again doesn't make it go to right again. Here is my code that i am using :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "game.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "input.h"

/* Game class
*  This class holds all information for our game loop
*/

namespace {
    const int FPS = 50;
    const int MAX_FRAME_TIME = 5 * 1000/ FPS;
}
Game::Game() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    this->gameLoop();
}
Game::~Game() {

}
void Game::gameLoop() {
    Graphics graphics;
    Input input;
    SDL_Event event;

    this->_player = Player(graphics, 100, 100);

    int LAST_UPDATE_TIME = SDL_GetTicks();
    //Start the game loop
    while(true){
        input.beginNewFrame();

        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                if(event.key.repeat == 0){
                    input.keyDownEvent(event);
                }
            }
            else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP){
                input.keyUpEvent(event);
            }
            else if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                return;
            }
        }
        if(input.wasKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE) == true){
            return;
        }
        else if(input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) == true) {
            this->_player.moveLeft();
        }
        else if(input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT) == true) {
            this->_player.moveRight();
        }

        if(!input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) && !input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT)){
            this->_player.stopMoving();
        }

    const int CURRENT_TIME_MS = SDL_GetTicks();
    int ELAPSED_TIME_MS = CURRENT_TIME_MS - LAST_UPDATE_TIME;
    this->update(std::min(ELAPSED_TIME_MS, MAX_FRAME_TIME));
    LAST_UPDATE_TIME = CURRENT_TIME_MS;
this->draw(graphics);
}

}
void Game::draw(Graphics &graphics){
    graphics.clear();

    this->_player.draw(graphics);

    graphics.flip();

}
void Game::update(float elapsedTime){
    this->_player.update(elapsedTime);
}
```

and for player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "graphics.h"

namespace player_constants {
    const float WALK_SPEED = 0.2f;
}

Player::Player() {}

Player::Player(Graphics &graphics, float x, float y) :
    AnimatedSprite(graphics, "MyChar.png", 0, 0, 16, 16, x, y, 100)
    {
        graphics.loadImage("MyChar.png");

        this->setupAnimations();
        this->playAnimation("RunRight");
    }
void Player::setupAnimations() {
    this->addAnimation(1, 0, 0, "IdleLeft", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
    this->addAnimation(1, 0, 16, "IdleRight", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
    this->addAnimation(3, 0, 0, "RunLeft", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
    this->addAnimation(3, 0, 16, "RunRight", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
}

void Player::animationDone(std::string currentAnimation) {}

void Player::moveLeft(){
    this->_dx = -player_constants::WALK_SPEED;
    this->playAnimation("RunLeft");
    this->_facing = LEFT;

}
void Player::moveRight(){
    this->_dx = player_constants::WALK_SPEED;
    this->playAnimation("RunRight");
    this->_facing = RIGHT;

}

void Player::stopMoving() {
    this->_dx = 0.0f;
    this->playAnimation(this->_facing == RIGHT ? "IdleRight" : "IdleLeft");
}
void Player::update(float elapsedTime) {
    //Move by dx
    this->_x += this->_dx * elapsedTime;

    AnimatedSprite::update(elapsedTime);
}

void Player::draw(Graphics &graphics) {
    AnimatedSprite::draw(graphics, this->_x, this->_y);
}
```

The main functions are 'moveLeft()', 'moveRight()' and 'stopMoving()' in player.cpp file above.

I think there's some problem in player.cpp file, can anyone help me with this as i have been trying to fix the problem for more than 3 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be caused by only polling for one event on each loop meaning that some events won't get processed. You should continue polling for events until there are no more events queued. See the [SDL docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) for bonus details.

In your case, you will need something like this:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
     if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
         if(event.key.repeat == 0){
             input.keyDownEvent(event);
         }
     }
     else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP){
         input.keyUpEvent(event);
     }
     else if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
        return;
     }
}
```